# Extreme points of a subset of dual space of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$K$ is compact Hausdorff, and $C(K)$ denotes the space of continuous functions on $K$. Let $\mathbb{1}\in C(K)$ denotes the constant function taking value 1, and let $S$ be the subset of $C(K)^*$ consisting of positive linear bounded functionals on $C(K)$ that map $\mathbb{1}$ to $1$. Show that the extreme points of $S$ are the point evaluation maps, $f\to f(x)$.

I know what $C(K)^*$ is like by Riesz Representation Theorem, and for any $T\in C(K)^*$, $T(f)=\int_K fd\mu$ for some $\mu$. It is also easy to check that $S$ is convex.

Can anyone give a hint for this? Thanks.

Comment: You need to show that a) evaluation maps are extreme points and b) each extreme point is an evaluation map. Do you have trouble with both parts?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit (deleted original content as it was a bad answer, as pointed out by the asker)

Hint:

1. Following what the asker pointed out in the comments to my former answer. Let $x\in K$, let $T_x$ be the evaluation functional $x\mapsto T_x(f)=f(x)$. Assume there is $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and $T_1\neq T_2\in S$ s.t. 
   $$
   f(x)=T_x(f)=\lambda T_1+(1-\lambda)T_2=\lambda\int_K f d\mu_1+(1-\lambda)\int_K f d\mu_2 
   $$
   Since $T_i\neq T$ for $i=1,2$, there is $y_i\neq x$ in the support of $\mu_i$. Can you use Urysohn's lemma here in a clever way to derive a contradiction?
2. Let $T\in S$. Then there is some $\mu$ s.t. 
   $$
   T(f)=\int_K fd\mu
   $$
   Assume $T$ is not an evaluation functional, which implies there are $x\neq y$ in the support of $\mu$. Since $T\in S$, $\mu(K)=1$. Then, there are $K_x\subset K$ and $K_y=K\setminus K_x \subset K$, with $x\in K_x$, $y\in K_y$ measurable with $\mu(K_x),\mu(K_y)>0$. Then
   $$
   T(f)=T_{K_x}(f)+T_{K_y}(f)=\int_K fd\mu_1+\int_K fd\mu_2
   $$
   with $\mu_1=\mu|_{K_x}$, $\mu_2=\mu|_{K_y}$. How to conclude $T$ is not an extreme point of $S$ using this?

Comment: Definition of extreme points should be: $T\in S$ is called extreme points if whenever $T=aT_1+(1-a)T_2$($0<a<1$, $T_1,T_2\in S$) we must have $T_1=T_2$. In equivalence, an extreme point of a convex set S in a real vector space is a point in S which does not lie in any open line segment joining two points of S. Could you please explain a little bit why you take two evaluation maps in part 1? Thanks.

Comment: I was considering $f(x)=(1-\lambda)\int_K f d\mu_1+\lambda\int_K f d\mu_2$, and try to find a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry. My answer is pretty bad. I didn't remember the definition of extreme point of a convex set correctly. Will edit it, significatively, in an attempt to somehow "salvage" it

Comment: Thanks, and this is helpful. For part 2, do you means that $\mu_1|_{K_x}=\mu|_{K_x}$ and such that $\mu_1(K)=1$ and same for $\mu_2$? Then there is a $\lambda$ such that $\int_K f d\mu=(1-\lambda)\int_K f d\mu_1+\lambda\int_K f d\mu_2$.

Comment: Glad to have been helpful, at last. In 2, what I meant was that $μ_1=μ|_{K_x}$, ie, $\mu_1(A)=\mu(A\cap K_x)$. But you are right, this, is not a probability measure. However, $\bar{μ}_1=\frac{μ_1}{\mu(K_x)}$ is a probability measure.